# Smoothing a contour with a lookup table / levels mapping (OpenCV)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, lookup-tables

I'm trying to smooth jagged contours drawn by `OpenCV's drawContours()` method. I'm applying a Gaussian blur to the contour, then trying to use a lookup table to map the pixel intensities.

However, I don't know what values to use in my lookup table. Right now I'm just guessing at arbitrary numbers. I put together a small mockup: The first two images are results directly from OpenCV. The last image is achieved through Photoshop's levels feature. As you can see it's smoother.

How do I know what values to use in my look up table?

```
std::vector<char> lut(256);
for (int i = 0; i <= 255; ++i) {

    if(i >= 75) lut[i] = 255;
    else if (i <= 25) lut[i] = 0;
    else if (i < 75 && i > 25) lut[i] = i;


}

cv::LUT(contoursOverlay, lut, contoursOverlay);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you think to apply only a dilatation filter (and optionally a blur afterward): http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html

It could be simpler and a better solution. In your case, I doubt there is good practise in this case. I'm not sure it's the good solution.